# Flask - How can we check when more number of users log in at the same time?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-socketio

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Login and validate the user.
        # user should be an instance of your `User` class
        login_user(user)
        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')
    return flask.render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

The above is my attempt at this. How can one send multiple login requests at the same time? Additionally, how can one check how the webapp behaves

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but your flask app will behave normally as expected when multiple users login simultaneously unless you are executing a huge script. Also, you have no need for the 'flask.' prefix which precedes flash and render_template.